# Вывод изображения без фона в углу экрана используя tkinter или PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, tkinter

Помогите пожалуйста с кодом, который выводит изображение в углу экрана без возможности взаимодействия (Водяной знак не активированной Windows 10)

[image: Пример на изображении]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PyQt5** вам в помощь :)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window | 
                          QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | 
                          QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)   
    window.setGeometry(30, 50, 100, 100)

    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(100, 100, 
                                            QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, 
                                            QtCore.Qt.FastTransformation)
    pal = window.palette()
    pal.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Normal, QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QBrush(pixmap))
    pal.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QBrush(pixmap))
    window.setPalette(pal)

    window.setMask(pixmap.mask())

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]